# Looping around an action if unsuccessful

Tags: loops, asp.net-mvc-4

I have code that tries to create a top up voucher code after receiving successful payment but I am encountering difficulties due to the fact that the RNSP server can only deal with one transaction at a time. I have the following code within an MVC control action what would be the best way of looping through this several times to a maximum of 5 if the voucher code could not be created on first attempt.

```
//Check the Realex response Code
if (tResp.ResultCode == 0)
{                    
   try
   {
      //Create the Voucher code
      ViewBag.VendCode = createVoucher(topupKeypadNumber.ToString(), topupAmount.ToString());
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      //SET THE VARIABLES TO BE DISPLAYED ON THE VEND CODE DISPLAY PAGE
      System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("Application", "GENERAL ERROR : " + ex.Message, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information);
      ViewBag.Title = "Vend Code Error";
      ViewBag.Message = "An error has occurred while retrieving your vend code. Please contact our customer service team.";
      return View("Info");
   }
   //SET THE VARIABLES TO BE DISPLAYED ON THE VEND CODE DISPLAY PAGE
   ViewBag.Title = "Issue Vend Code";
   ViewBag.Message = ViewBag.VendCode;
   return View("Success");
}
```

Comment: Did the answer work for you? You haven't responded yet.

Comment: Hi psyLogic I used the logic in the try while thanks for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
if (tResp.ResultCode == 0)
{    
   int maximumRetryLimit=5; 
   int retryCount=0; 
   bool isVoucherCreated;     
   try
   {
      while(retryCount<=maximumRetryLimit)
      {    //Create the Voucher code
         ViewBag.VendCode = createVoucher(topupKeypadNumber.ToString(), topupAmount.ToString());
         if(ViewBag.VendCode!=null) 
         {
            isVoucherCreated=true;
            break;
         }
         ++retryCount;
      }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      //SET THE VARIABLES TO BE DISPLAYED ON THE VEND CODE DISPLAY PAGE
      System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("Application", "GENERAL ERROR : " + ex.Message, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information);
      ViewBag.Title = "Vend Code Error";
      ViewBag.Message = "An error has occurred while retrieving your vend code. Please contact our customer service team.";
      return View("Info");
   }
   //SET THE VARIABLES TO BE DISPLAYED ON THE VEND CODE DISPLAY PAGE
   if(isVoucherCreated)
   {
      ViewBag.Title = "Issue Vend Code";
      ViewBag.Message = ViewBag.VendCode;
      return View("Success");
   }
   else
   {
       ViewBag.Title = "Vend Code Error";
       ViewBag.Message = "An error has occurred while retrieving your vend code. Please contact our customer service team.";
       return View("Info");
   }
}
```